# Could not Signup for Windows Azure

Tags: azure, windows-8

I am a developer from Nepal. I tried to create a account for developing application using Windows Azure. But I could not complete my signup for my windows azure account. 
Is Windows Azure account limited to some countries?
Are there any alternatives to create Windows Azure account?

Comment: I've had trouble with it in the US as well.  It may be b/c they are restructuring the test/development side of things with more security.  I think they are only allowing one primary administrator but multiple sub administrators for a given organization.

Comment: It's worth reposting this on Azure support forums if the issue persists: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/contact/

Comment: What exactly error message do you get?

Answer (score 2):

Windows Azure is only supported in 84 countries (I thought it was 89) of which Nepal unfortunately is not one of them, see the [FAQ](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/faq/) I don't think there are any alternatives to this as you need a credit card from one of the approved countries to register.

*Update -  it is 89, the FAQ is a little bit out of date, Nepal is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Azure has been made available in Nepal Since August. You can sign in directly by choosing Nepal and your Nepal Based Mobile No.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply for student subscription. Azure is free for learner with limited credit. You need either subscription key or forward you microsoft account. I might help you by transfer certain credit from my MSDN subscription.